# Using regular expression to find specific strings between parentheses (including parentheses)

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I am trying to use regular expression to find specific strings between parentheses in a string like the one below:

```
foo = '((peach W/O juice) OR apple OR (pear W/O water) OR kiwi OR (lychee AND sugar) OR (pineapple W/O salt))'
```

Specifically, I want to find only `(peach W/O juice)`, `(pear W/O water)`, and `(pineapple W/O salt)`.

I tried `lookahead` and `lookbehind`, but was unable to obtain the correct results.

For example, when I do the following RegEx:

```
import re
regex = '(?<=[\s\(])\([^\)].*\sW/O\s[^\)].*\)(?=[\)\s])'
re.findall(regex, foo)
```

I end up with the entire string:

```
['(peach W/O juice) OR apple OR (pear W/O water) OR kiwi OR (lychee AND sugar) OR (pineapple W/O salt)']
```

#### EDIT:

I found the problem:

Instead of `[\)].*`, I should do `[\)]*`, which would give me the correct result:

```
regex = '(?<=[\s\(])\([^\)]*\sW/O\s[^\)]*\)(?=[\)\s])'

re.findall(regex, foo)
['(peach W/O juice)', '(pear W/O water)', '(pineapple W/O salt)']
```

Comment: Suggestion: How about just find all the strings which inside quotes, and then use `if 'W/O' in string` to filter the strings which you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is that your `.*` operators are being greedy - they will consume as much as they can if you don't put a `?` after them: `.*?`. Also, note that since you *want* the parentheses, you shouldn't need the lookahead/lookbehind operations; they will exclude the parentheses they find.

Instead of fully debugging your regex, I decided to just rewrite it:

```
>>> import re
>>> foo ='((peach W/O juice) OR apple OR (pear W/O water) OR kiwi OR (lychee AND sugar) OR (pineapple W/O salt))'
>>> regex = '\([a-zA-Z ]*?W/O.*?\)'
>>> re.findall(regex, foo)
['(peach W/O juice)', '(pear W/O water)', '(pineapple W/O salt)']
```

Here's the breakdown:

`\(` captures the leading parentheses - note that it's escaped

`[a-zA-Z ]` captures all alphabetical characters and a space (note the space after Z before the closing bracket) I used this instead of `.` so that no other parentheses will be captured. Using the period operator would cause `(lychee AND sugar) OR (pineapple W/O salt)` to be captured as one match.

`*?` the `*` causes the characters in the bracket to match 0 or more times, but the `?` says to *only capture as many as you need to make a match*

`W/O` captures the "W/O" that you're looking for

`.*?` captures any more characters (again, non-greedy because of `?`)

`\)` captures the trailing parenthesese

Comment: Thanks!1 I just realized where the problem is: In `'(?<=[\s\(])\([^\)].*\sW/O\s[^\)].*\)(?=[\)\s])'`, instead `[^\)].*`, I should use `[^\)]*`

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to include parenthesis in the result, you don't need to use lookarounds. You can use a character class that exclude the closing parenthesis. In this way, you are sure that W/O is between parenthesis:

```
re.findall(r'\([^()]* W/O [^)]*\)', foo)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to use lookahead and lookbehind because there are other occurrences of the pattern that I do not want to match, which I did not mention in my questions